# How do I apply css animations to angular2 components before they are destroyed/removed?

Tags: css, animation, dom, angular

Good morning!

While we wait for the new ng2-animate library to be completed, is there another way to animate elements before they're removed from the dom?

I am using an element with an *ngIf attribute. When the element is added to the DOM, I can animate it in with no problems. When the element is removed, transitions don't apply.

I've tried using the lifecycle hooks by listening for an *animationend* event in ngOnDestroy, and I've tried using renderer. The latter isn't documented yet.

Do I just need to lean on JQuery for now?

Comment: I am wondering how did you manage it. You ended up with on jQuery or found a solution?

Comment: I believe this isn't an issue in Angular 5 anymore, and that is what we are using now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug where a pull request already exists https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6768

> i found a bug which is `detachView` method removing DOM before `animateNodeLeave`.

Comment: The new Animation module in Angular2 should solve this (not tried myself yet).